# how to delete bookmark from LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

In LibreOffice 4.3.5.2 nor in LibreOffice 3.5.7.2 I cannot remove a Bookmark. Please advise me, thanks!

Comment: Please describe, how you're trying to delete the bookmark, what you expect to happen, what happens instead, and any possible error messages or warnings. Use screenshots, if you think they're helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the upper menu-bar go to **Insert** -  **Bookmarks...** .

Bookmarks list will appear:

[image]

Select the bookmark you want to delete and press **Delete** button.